# Update table using stored procedure in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2012

i'm having trouble on how do i update my table using datagridview and stored procedure. here is the code;

```
Private Sub INPUTGrades()
    Dim strConn As String = "Data Source=Jansen;Initial Catalog=SLCBRegistrarDB;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConn)

    CMD = New SqlCommand
    CMD.Connection = sqlCon
    CMD.CommandText = "PostingofGRADE"
    CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcademicYear", cmbAcademicYear.Text)
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Period", cmbPeriod.Text)
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", cmbSection.Text)
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseCode", cmbSubjectCode.Text)
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescriptiveTitle", cmbDescription.Text)
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcademicLevel", cmbAcadLevel.Text)

    CMD.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StudentID", SqlDbType.Int))
    CMD.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Grade", SqlDbType.NVarChar))

    sqlCon.Open()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvSubjectsEntry.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then
            CMD.Parameters("@StudentID").Value = row.Cells(1).Value
            CMD.Parameters("@Grade").Value = row.Cells(0).Value

            Dim RowsAffected As Integer = CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If RowsAffected > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Grade Successfully Posted.")
            Else
                MsgBox("Failed!")
            End If
        End If
    Next
    sqlCon.Close()
End Sub
```

And this is the Stored Procedure:

```
USE [SLCBRegistrarDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[PostingofGRADE]    Script Date: 
7/21/2017 9:38:16 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[PostingofGRADE]

@StudentID Int,
@AcademicYear nvarchar(50),
@Period nvarchar(50),
@Section nvarchar(10),
@CourseCode nvarchar(50),
@DescriptiveTitle nvarchar(100),
@Grade nvarchar(50),
@AcademicLevel nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

    Declare @AcademicLevelID int
    Declare @SchoolID int
    Declare @TypeofStudentID int
    Declare @CourseID int
    Declare @PeriodID int
    Declare @AcademicYearID int
    Declare @SectionID int
    Declare @SubjectCode int

        SELECT @AcademicLevelID=AcadLevelID FROM [Academic Level] WHERE 
[Academic Level]=@AcademicLevel

        SELECT @PeriodID=SemID FROM SemesterList WHERE Description=@Period

        SELECT @SectionID=SectionID FROM Section WHERE Section=@Section

        SELECT @AcademicYearID=[SY ID] FROM SchoolYear WHERE [School Year]=@AcademicYear

 SELECT @SubjectCode=StudentAcademicRecords.[Subject Code]
 FROM         StudentAcademicRecords INNER JOIN
         [Class Schedule LINE] ON StudentAcademicRecords.[Subject Code] = 
 [Class Schedule LINE].SchedID INNER JOIN
         Curriculum ON [Class Schedule LINE].[Subject Code] = Curriculum.
[Subject Code] INNER JOIN
         ListofSubjects ON Curriculum.SubjectID = ListofSubjects.SubjectID 
 INNER JOIN
         SchoolYear ON StudentAcademicRecords.[Academic Year] = SchoolYear.
 [SY ID] INNER JOIN
         SemesterList ON StudentAcademicRecords.Period = SemesterList.SemID 
AND Curriculum.SemesterID = SemesterList.SemID
WHERE        (ListofSubjects.[Course No.] = @CourseCode) AND 
(ListofSubjects.[Descriptive Title] = @DescriptiveTitle) AND 
         (StudentAcademicRecords.StudentID = @StudentID) AND 
(SemesterList.Description = @Period) AND (SchoolYear.[School Year] = 
@AcademicYear)

BEGIN
    UPDATE StudentAcademicRecords
    SET StudentID =@StudentID, [Academic Level] =@AcademicLevelID, Period 
=@PeriodID, [Academic Year] =@AcademicYearID, Section =@SectionID, [Subject 
Code] =@SubjectCode, Grade =@Grade
    FROM StudentAcademicRecords
    WHERE [Subject Code]=@SubjectCode AND StudentID=@StudentID
END

END
```

If i try to run the code, nothing happens with the table. no changes at all. I tried running in the sql server query, and it works fine but in my vb.net code, it does not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If Not row.IsNewRow Then will only be a true condition only if no data has been entered for the grid row. Not sure if that's what's happening here causing your command to not execute.

Comment: I don't know what caused the problem. is their any way how to do this..?

Comment: When you call `ExecuteNonQuery`, one of three things will happen. Firstly, the call may succeed and return a value greater than zero, which means that that many records were affected. Secondly, the call may succeed and return zero, which means that the SQL executed successfully but no records were affected. Finally, the call may fail and throw and exception. Which is it in your case?  If it's the first then you are saving changes and you're just not looking for them correctly.  If it's one of the others then you need to address issues with either your data or your SQL code.

Comment: If i run the stored procedure in sql server query and add values on it, it works fine, meaning some rows in the table which i want to update, works fine..but if i call this stored procedure in the visual studio with vb.net code and run the code, it worked but the problem is, no rows in the table are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ow I'm Sorry guys..My Code is correct..it works perfectly.. i just inserted a wrong entry in combobox items in my windows form that makes the SELECT Statement in the SQL Code returns 0.. It works fine.. i'm sorry guys, that's a shame.

"Description" also should be replaced with "[Sem.]". I just specified the wrong column name. Too many arguments that twisted my mind. Sorry guys. this is a good code.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do isn't exactly like what you have, but it works for me, and maybe it'll work for you, i use a UPSERT Parameterized query, essentially it checks the existing database table to see if the key to be inserted matches any existing and if it does, performs an update, and if not, inserts that new data as a new row, here is an example of a looped UPSERT query that I use in my code:

```
    Dim Connexion As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(dbLocations(0, 1))
        Dim updateStatement As String = Nothing
        Dim updatecommand As New SqlCommand(updateStatement, Connexion)
        Try
            Connexion.Open()
            query = String.Empty
            query &= "UPDATE schedule SET Task = @Task, Complete = @Complete, Start_date = @Start_date, "
            query &= "Due_date = @Due_date, JRID = @JRID, Task_Manager = @Task_Manager, Entered_By = @Entered_By, Time_Entered = @Time_Entered "
            query &= "WHERE TaskID = @TaskID "
            query &= "IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT INTO schedule ( TaskID, Task, start_date, Due_Date, Complete, Task_Manager, JRID, Entered_By, Time_Entered)"
            query &= " VALUES ( @TaskID, @Task, @start_date, @Due_Date, @Complete, @Task_Manager, @JRID, @Entered_By, @Time_Entered);"

            updatecommand.CommandText = query

            If MainSchedule.isokclicked = 1 Then
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In MainSchedule.DataGridView1.Rows
                    If Not (row.Cells(0).Value = Nothing) Then
                        insertcommand.Parameters.Clear()
                        insertcommand.CommandText = query
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskID", row.Cells(0).Value)
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Complete", "False")
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task", row.Cells(1).Value)
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start_date", row.Cells(2).Value)
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Due_Date", row.Cells(3).Value)
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JRID", txtJRID.Text)
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task_Manager", row.Cells(4).Value)
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entered_By", GetUserName())
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time_Entered", Now)
                        insertcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End If
                    keypos = keypos + 1
                Next
                Connexion.Close()
            Else
            End If
```

Comment: So you haven't used a stored procedures here. The thing is, i just want to update my bridge table,.the code runs perfectly with other stored procedures like INSERT, but if i use UPDATE it does not.

Comment: See my response to your question on Microsoft forums https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d51c93ff-8ce2-446f-b78f-874f6ce7ca45/update-data-from-datagridview-to-database-using-stored-procedure-in-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral